# Transform a one-liner from Numpy Python to Julia that involves mapping one 2D Array onto another 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, julia

Julia beginner here. I need to so some jugglery with a couple of matrices. My goal is as follows:

Given a certain matrix Matrix1 as:

[image]

, and a binary matrix Matrix2 as this:

[image]

, I want to allocate the elements from Matrix1 to Matrix2 such that I have a final matrix Matrix3, which looks like:

[image]

In Python, the following one liner worked:

`Matrix3= Matrix1.flatten()[(np.cumsum(Matrix2).reshape(Matrix2.shape)-1)] * Matrix2`

Can anyone help me in writing a similar piece of code (preferably one liner if possible) in Julia?

**Extension**    -  I have gotten the answer for the above question from @cbk. As an extension to the question above. I was thinking of generalizing it for higher dimensional matrices. So, suppose Matrix1 has dimension (4,6,6) and the binary matrix Matrix2 has dimension (4,12,12). The allocation problem remains the same. How would then you approach it? Can someone kindly help me in it?

Comment: How important is 1 liner vs performance?

Comment: Quite important actually. But still not a very strong preference.

Answer (score 2):

The main "gotchas" are that (1) you want to fill Matrix3 with the appropriate type of zero and (2) Julia is column-major, so you need to permute. This should do the trick though:

`(Matrix3 = zeros(eltype(Matrix1),size(Matrix2)))'[Matrix2'[:]] .= Matrix1'[:]`

A similar option would be

`(Matrix3 = zeros(eltype(Matrix1),size(Matrix2)))'[vec(Matrix2')] .= vec(Matrix1')`

but this was slightly less efficient than the above, as measured by `@btime`

edit: If `Matrix2` originally contains integers instead of Booleans, you will need to convert before indexing with `Matrix2`, e.g.:

`(Matrix3 = zeros(eltype(Matrix1),size(Matrix2)))'[Bool.(Matrix2'[:])] .= Matrix1'[:]`

Comment: Upon running, I am seeing a 'BoundsError' on this. For now it did not work, I will check it later and post it here.

Comment: Ah, so you'll get a BoundsError if `Matrix2` happens to be an array of integer ones and zeros instead of an array of Booleans. Using `Bool.(Matrix2)` should fix this.

Comment: Since I assumed your `Matrix2` was an array of Booleans to start, I also missed a potentially simpler one-liner if you want to overwrite the original `Matrix2` with elements from `Matrix1`: `Matrix2'[Bool.(Matrix2')] .= Matrix1'[:]`

Comment: Your solutions work perfectly my friend. Thanks a lot.
Sorry, I am new with Julia and I did not took care of Mat2 being a boolen :)

Comment: Hi, can i ask you for a help in extension to this question. I was thinking of generalizing it for higher dimensional matrices. So, suppose Matrix1 has dimension (4,6,6) and the binary matrix Matrix2 has dimension (4,12,12). The allocation problem remains the same. Can you please help with the code here?

Comment: Oof, I have a harder time reasoning about higher dimensional objects. If you can find an answer in another language though, I could probably help translate it to Julia.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In Python the same one liner worked even with 3D arrays. ```Matrix3= Matrix1.flatten()[(np.cumsum(Matrix2).reshape(Matrix2.shape)-1)] * Matrix2```. I will try to break down very briefly what happens in Python. Think it for the original 2D case. 1. By using cumcum, reshaping and sutracting 1, you create a 2D array, whose values you use as index to smartly map the flattened array. Finally you set the redundant, repetitvie values to zero (which resulted from cumsum) by multiplying with Matrix2 i.e. only keep those values where Matrix2 has 1's in it.Same extends for 3D case

Comment: Note that, however, I do not need to go any beyond the 3D arrays :)